# Please help solve for the variables A and B

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ 4A - 2B = 10 $ and $ B = 2A - 5 $.

Help Solve for the algebraic variables "$A$" and "$B$"  using elimination, substitution or graphing from above two equations.

Some say it is one equation only, some say it is inconsistent , some say they are dependent, these two are insufficient etc., but how so?

Comment: Replace B in the first equation. Then you'll have just an equation in A

Comment: Is it "No solution"

Comment: @Jayb It is not "no solution"--in fact, as my answer points out, there are *infinitely* many.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

They are both the same equation - rearrange equation 2 to get $2A-B=5$ so $A=(B+5)/2$, which is a line, for example if $B=1, A=3$.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Mark Perry points out, the equations you have are equal (i.e., they are "the same"). To see this, you may use substitution if you like:
$$
4A-2B=10\Longleftrightarrow 4A-2(2A-5)=10\Longleftrightarrow 10=10.
$$
Since $10=10$ is *always* true, you know that both of your equations are satisfied regardless of what value for $B$ you pick. Hence, there are *infinitely* many solutions to your system of equations. You may first pick whatever value you want for $A$ or $B$ and then the corresponding value will be determined. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If equation  $4A - 2B = 10$ rearange we get $B = 2A - 5$ and all solutions lie a line $$\{(A,2A-5):A\in\mathbb R\}$$

Comment: Thank you i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

These are not two, but only one repeated equation. It not possible to solve for the point of intersection of two lines. However, if an extra condition of integer solution is imposed, then possibility of a solution is increased.